# Nicely tabulate a list of strings for printing

Tags: python, strings

I have a list of strings of variable lengths, and I want to pretty-print them so they are lining up in columns.  I have the following code, which works as I want it to currently, but I feel it is a bit ugly.  How can I simplify it/make it more pythonic (without changing the output behaviour)?

For starters I think I could probably use the alignment `'<'` option of the [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) stuff if I could just figure out the syntax properly...

```
def tabulate(words, termwidth=79, pad=3):
  width = len(max(words, key=len))
  ncols = max(1, termwidth // (width + pad))
  nrows = len(words) // ncols + (1 if len(words) % ncols else 0)
  #import itertools
  #table = list(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(words)]*ncols, fillvalue=''))  # row-major
  table = [words[i::nrows] for i in xrange(nrows)]                          # column-major
  return '\n'.join(''.join((' '*pad + x.ljust(width) for x in r)) for r in table)
```

Comment: Not worth an answer, but you can get your rounded-up-not-down integer division to compute `nrows` in a much more compact form as `nrows = (len(words) - 1) // ncols + 1`. Seee e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a better way when I was writing that... I'd just forgotten the usual trick (which, actually, I usually used adding the denominator - 1 to the numerator, i.e. `(len(words) + ncols - 1) // ncols` ... it seems to be equivalent to your trick

Comment: I found a nice alternative, after `pip install prettytable`.  No need to reinvent the wheel I guess ..

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more readable version:

```
def tabulate(words, termwidth=79, pad=3):
    width = len(max(words, key=len)) + pad
    ncols = max(1, termwidth // width)
    nrows = (len(words) - 1) // ncols + 1
    table = []
    for i in xrange(nrows):
        row = words[i::nrows]
        format_str = ('%%-%ds' % width) * len(row)
        table.append(format_str % tuple(row))
    return '\n'.join(table)
```

Most notably, I've defined `width` to include padding and using string formatting to generate a format string to format each row ;).